# Can you waterproof Luxury Vinyl Tile floors without grout?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, tile, grout, vinyl

My questions are on the use of Luxury Vinyl Tile (LVT) flooring - my preference is to use the LVT without grout. However, I'm skeptical on how well the LVT will hold up to moisture without the grout and cleaning will be an issue.  Am I right about the need for waterproofing or would the flooring work well any way?  Is there a way to waterproof the joints on LVT without grouting? If water gets between the floor tiles as you step out of the shower will it cause even bigger problems?

Comment: Friendly reminder to anyone reading this: grout isn't waterproof, the product Ben Welborn mentioned below however is waterproof.

Answer (score 1):

In some areas, you can get away without having grout, but the tiles will be more susceptible to damage because grout (or something) adds strength to the floor (and keeps the tiles in place). You may have seen or heard about how some people make really tight fittings with beveled tile, and they don't use grout. This is more for areas that are onramental or where contact with water is unlikely.

In the bathroom, I think it's safe to say that you need something between the tiles especially because there will be water (on the floor). Another purpose for grout is to protect the underlayment from water... water damage could be summarized as swelling which can cause lifting/ungluing of tiles and warping and loosening of the wood and rotten/weakened wood or just plain mold and mildew. And yes, cleaning will be an issue without grout or something between the tiles.

There are alternatives to cement grout; you should search online for grout alternatives. Epoxy and caulk come to mind. If you don't put something in there, something else (dirt) will eventually fill in the gaps.

Edit- (based on the comment "my ex-husband already laid the tiles without spacing for grout")I don't like to promote products, but I'm not aware of any other silane vinyl sealers, so try a product called Infuze. Here's the [technical data sheet](http://galleher.com/wp-content/uploads/test/IVC-infuze-seam-sealer-spec-msds-01-05-12.pdf). Like I said, it's a silane product that I think will work for this. It's kind of messy and smelly and dries quickly (so work as quickly); it will definitely seal vinyl seams. I think it chemically bonds to vinyl to create vinyl silane. It dries clear and doesn't discolor.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, my ex-husband already laid the tiles without spacing for grout so I'm looking for a sealant that could go over the tiles to seal them from water and dirt. I have already caulked around the tub, toilet, and walls, but my son is a teenager that doesn't always stay on the bath mat when he steps out of the shower and I frequently find the floor wet afterwards. I know I could use a polyurethane, but the tiles are white and gray marble and I don't want them to yellow.

Comment: @DIYMommy I'm not big on recommending products, but I used something called infuze once for sealing a jagged tear in a vinyl floor. I think it could work for this. I'll edit my post with a picture.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Someone also recommended Rejuvenate floor protector so I'm going to do a little more research on each product. I will post an update after I try one.

Comment: @DIYMommy Rejuvenate floor protector is floor polish... (specifically it is a chemical called Diethylene Glycol Monoethyl Ether) it's added to some brands of floor wax. Floor wax isn't actually wax, it's typically an acrylic polymer. But again sometimes they mix the acrylic polymer with polishing compounds like Diethylene Glycol Monoethyl Ether.

Comment: @DIYMommy Floor wax might work for you... but you need to keep up with it. Waxing the floor is a "regular" sort of chore.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps I don't understand your meaning. Click, one type of vinyl flooring, doesn't use grout. It is waterproof.

[image]